# Nightwatch: Override Function in Page Object

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I have created a page object model in Nightwatch but I would like to override some functions for customization. How would I achieve that?

```
module.exports = {
url: 'http://localhost:63916/Login/Login', 

commands: [{
    navigateToImportBatch() {
        this
            .click('@importManager')
            .click('@importBatch')

            return this.api;
    }
};
```

How can I override the navigateToImportBatch function? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to override globally or just in one step definition?

Answer (score 2):

Override globally:

```
// your current module to override, e.g. loginPageModel.js
let module = {
  url: 'http://localhost:63916/Login/Login', 

  commands: [{
    navigateToImportBatch() {
      this.click('@importManager')
        .click('@importBatch');

      return this.api;
    }
  }]
};
module.exports = module;
```

And then define a new module, override whatever commands you need to and export it.

```
// loginOverride.js
let LoginOverride = require('./loginPageModel'); // whatever the path to your module is called

LoginOverRide.commands[0].navigateToImportBatch = function() {
   // your new implementation
}

module.exports = LoginOverride;
```

Then simply import the module that overrides the base implementation in your step definition/s.

```
let LoginModel = require('./loginOverride');

// use as normal
```

Alternately you can use the same strategy in a step definition without defining a new page model, and just override the implementation from the step definition.